# What is the translation of הרכבה מזגית / הרכבה שכונית?

Tags: hebrew, translation

In the introduction to Shev Shmattsa letter 'מ' he talks about various cases of two things that combine to become one (the guf and the neshama, a mule, someone who is half eved half ben chorin, etc). He says that some things are 'הרכבה מזגית' whereas others are 'הרכבה שכונית'. I'm trying to figure out the translation of these terms.

It seems that הרכבה מזגית means that the two things combine to become one new בריאה, which is not the case by הרכבה שכונית. But I would still like to know the exact translation of the two terms if anyone knows.

edit - I would venture to guess that שכונית comes from the word for neighbor, and it means a combination of two things that only co-exist side by side, but don't actually combine to become one.... but I still don't know what מזגית (or הרכבה ממוזגת) means.

Answer (score 2):

According to Rb Avraham Gurwicz (Gateshead) - *harkavah mishchis* is a mixture and *harkavah mizgis* is a compound.

So for example, if you have a *chatzi eved chatzi ben chorin*, you can have a *chakirah* if this is a *harkavah mishchis*, and there just happen to be elements of *ben chorin* and *eved* in the same person, or if this is a *harkavah mizgis* so that these elements interact to create a new type.

Comment: @Shalom https://biodifferences.com/difference-between-mixtures-and-compounds.html The mixture contains two or more substances mixed, but neither chemically as well as not in inexact quantity while compound includes two or more elements combined chemically and in a fixed ratio. For instance, Seawater, Crude oil, Mineral oils, Alloys (Brass, Bronze), etc., are some of the mixtures, Water (H2O), Hydrogen Peroxide (H2O2), Sodium Chloride (NaCl), Baking Soda (NaHCO3), etc. are the name of some compounds.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's a step further than "mixing bowl" and "melting pot." I like the chemical analogy, thank you!

Comment: Of course the term "meziga" itself used Talmudically isn't a true compound, but okay, you had to call it something.

Comment: @Shalom Fair call